# GeoServer 2.9.0 fails on MacOS with "Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI"

Tags: geoserver, java

I am installing GeoServer 2.9.0 (Mac OSX Installer) for the first time on MacOS X 10.11.5 and it fails with the error below. I have no ~/Library/Java folder, my /Library/Java/Extensions is empty and the CLASSPATH environment variable is unset. The `java -version` is 1.8.0_31, but the application appears to provide its own 1.8.0_73 JDK.

Any ideas?

```
WARNING: Module not found [ssl]
2016-07-29 16:48:39.629:INFO::startup executor: Logging initialized @4032ms
2016-07-29 16:48:39.822:INFO:oejs.Server:startup executor: jetty-9.2.13.v20150730
2016-07-29 16:48:39.851:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:startup executor: Deployment monitor [file:/Applications/GeoServer.app/Contents/Java/webapps/] at interval 1
2016-07-29 16:48:40.845:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:startup executor: NO JSP Support for /geoserver, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2016-07-29 16:48:41.225:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:startup executor: FAILED o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@97a1816{/geoserver,file:/Applications/GeoServer.app/Contents/Java/webapps/geoserver/,STARTING}{/geoserver}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI
    at org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextInitialized(GeoserverInitStartupListener.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)
    at org.geoserver.console.GeoServerConsole$ProductionHandler.start(GeoServerConsole.java:129)
    at org.geoserver.console.GeoServerConsole$Frame$8.run(GeoServerConsole.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-07-29 16:48:41.227:WARN:oejd.DeploymentManager:startup executor: Unable to reach node goal: started
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI
    at org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextInitialized(GeoserverInitStartupListener.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)
    at org.geoserver.console.GeoServerConsole$ProductionHandler.start(GeoServerConsole.java:129)
    at org.geoserver.console.GeoServerConsole$Frame$8.run(GeoServerConsole.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-07-29 16:48:41.316:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:startup executor: Started ServerConnector@4308d56{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
```

**update:** I downloaded 2.8.4 and this works without any issues, but I would still be curious to know whether this is a bug in 2.9.0 (didn't see anything of note in the issue tracker) or something related to a configuration?

**update:** Have tried to add the jai files (jai_codec-1.1.3.jar, jai_core-1.1.3.jar, jai_imageio-1.1.jar) to `/Applications/GeoServer 2.9.0.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib`, but I still get the issue. Also tried putting them in `/Applications/GeoServer 2.9.0.app/Contents/Java/lib/`, but no luck either. Note, that the bundled jdk is being used, per lsof.

Comment: I have similar error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651163/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-javax-media-jai-jai

Comment: that is a warning not an error - make sure you have install JAI in the JDK/JRE that is actually running GeoServer.

Comment: It may be a warning, but works out as an error, since access to /geoserver/web creates a 404. It is using the JDK bundled with the app, so if jai is not there it would suggest a packaging issue?

Comment: @AndreM Any luck with latest version ? I am also facing same waring/error with geoserver 2.10.1.

Comment: Haven't tried using GeoServer since, due to this becoming a blocking issue for me.

Comment: @AndreM I think you'll find that there are no `jai_*.jar` files included in GeoServer 2.8.x (my previous install was 2.3.2, where I definitely had to install them myself), they _are_ included in 2.9+, so you should just be able to get away with the defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading and installing GeoServer 2.10.2 provided a working solution for me, suggesting the issue was likely a packaging issue.

Note: I did not need to install any supplementary packages or libraries to make this work. I am also using macOS 10.12.3 at this point.

Answer (score 3):

you can find this solution on this site:
https://github.com/mossiso/notes/blob/master/install-geonetwork.md

In short. You have to remove all JAI jars from your Java installation.

EDIT:
I try explain more. I don't know exactly why is so situation that Geoserver version 2.10.x or 2.9.x has a conflict with Java library. It strange for me because on Geoserver 2.8.x everything works great.

I suggest first copy JAI libray to another destination and remove them from Java instalation folder:
jai_codec-1.1.3.jar
jai_core-1.1.3.jar
jai_imageio-1.1.jar

geoserver has the same librarys and it should work.

Comment: Also, not sure I would feel comfortable touching anything under ``/System/Library/`` without a good reason, given risk for side-effect?

Comment: afaik, your Java installation isn't going to include any JAI jars--you used have to install those yourself. However, _now_ (presumably starting at GeoServer 2.9), GeoServer is including JAI, and apparently even though the version numbers are the same they're not the ones I downloaded from Oracle. So I removed the ones I downloaded, and all's right with the world.

Comment: If you are on a more recent version of macOS, (and have upgraded from an older version) you will need to [disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) in order to delete these JAI jars